# Flutter CircularProgressIndicator not aligned center

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Not sure what is going on here I have `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,` and still not aligning to the vertical center you can see the issue here its pretty fast and I'm talking about the loader not the one for the images

[image]

my code

```
if (value.isLoading) {
        return Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Center(
              child: loadingWidget(),
            ),
          ],
        );
      }
```

Here is the full code

```
return SizedBox(
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
  child: Consumer<DogProvider>(
    builder: (context, value, child) {
      if (value.isLoading) {
        return Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Center(
              child: loadingWidget(),
            ),
          ],
        );
      }
      if (value.dogsList.isEmpty || value.error.isNotEmpty) {
        return Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Lottie.asset(
              'assets/animations/no-dog-animation.json',
              width: 500,
              height: 250,
            ),
            const Center(
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 15, 10, 0),
                child: Text(
                  "You haven't added a dog yet!",
                  style: AppStyles.noDataTextStyle,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      }

      return SizedBox(
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 65.0,
                left: 18.0,
                right: 18.0,
              ),
              child: Text(
                dogsCount(value.dogsList.length),
                style: AppStyles.listsHeaderTextStyle,
              ),
            ),
            ListView.builder(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 5,
                bottom: 20,
                left: 15,
                right: 15,
              ),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              itemCount: value.dogsList.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => DogProfileCardWidget(
                dogInfo: value.dogsList[index],
                editProfile: openProfileScreen,
                dogIndex: index,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
);
```

Ok so the issue is with the SizedBox

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the SizeBox which did not have a height I fixed this by wrapping the loader with a sizebox and giving it a hight

```
 return SizedBox(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
```

Comment: Not sure why would you wrap all that with a screen-sized sized box. You can simply return a Center widget with Loader child. The layout seems unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: The center widget did not work, that is what I had. It was due to the size box and how the page is loaded inside another page

Comment: The first thing I noticed is that your loadingWidget is rendering over the Top-Row-Widget(probably AppBar). I haven't seen your full code, I guess there might be a reason for it. But if it seems off to you as well, you can consider using a Column for main layout, with children being your top-widget-row & Listing Section with Loader(only wrapped by Center).

Answer (score 0):

#### Use Sizedbox Widget for spacing

```html
if (value.isLoading) {
        return Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxsiAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            const SizedBox(height: 120.0),
            Center(
              child: loadingWidget(),
            ),
          ],
        );
      }
```